# extracting attribute value out of the "aria-label" tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the rating of the products from Sephora's website.  However, when I try to extract the rating, it does not work the way I want it to.  I guess my question is I don't know how to target that tag b/c it has a different structure compares to other data I needed to extract.  Please help!

Here is the website:https://www.sephora.com/product/revitalizing-supreme-global-anti-aging-creme-P384342?icid2=products%20grid:p384342

The picture here is the value that I wanted to extract.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD0YZ.jpg)

And I also attached my code here.

```
final_products = [] #empty list to append the dictionary in to before passing in to a DataFrame
for i in range(0, len(link_list)):
#for i in urls.index:
     current_url = link_list[i]
     resource = requests.get(current_url)
     current_data = resource.text
     soup = BeautifulSoup(current_data, 'html.parser')
     #gathering the data from the pages
     try:
        product = {}
        product['Name'] = soup.find('span', {'class': 'css-0'}).text
        product['Price'] = soup.find('div', {'class': 'css-slwsq8'}).text
        product['Num_of_reviews'] = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'css-2rg6q7'})[0].text
        product['Num_of_Likes'] = soup.find('span', {'data-at': 'product_love_count'}).text
        product['Rating'] = soup.find('a', {'aria-label'})
        #append the empty list to later make in to a dataframe
        final_products.append(product)
    except: 
        pass
```

Comment: "it does not work the way I want it to". What happens, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi Karl, so I expect it to return something like "4 stars", "4.2 stars".... etc , but it returns "None".  And my idea is to start from the tag above it to target the aria-label attribute but I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it

Comment: If you're ok with using lxml instead of beautifulsoup (it's easier with xpath, I believe), I can post an answer.